# Help with loading local video file

Tags: actionscript-3, video, flex3

I'm currently having a problem on loading video files from my local host. i have tried compiling my mxml with -use-network=false. but i cant do so because my project is also loading videos from youtube via a youtubeloader.

code im using for loading my local vid

```
<:mx:VideoDisplay id="vid" source="media/MyVideo.flv" height="250" width="250"/>
```

or is there any other way to load local video files?

Here is the error

> SecurityError: Error #2148: SWF file
>   file:///C|/Users/ifcdu1/Desktop/MP/Main.swf
>   cannot access local resource
>   file:///C|/Users/ifcdu1/Desktop/MP/media/MyVideo.flv.
>   Only local-with-filesystem and trusted
>   local SWF files may access local
>   resources.

And here is the error if i compile with -use-network=false

> SecurityError: Error #2028:
>   Local-with-filesystem SWF file
>   file:///C|/Users/ifcdu1/Desktop/MP/Main.swf
>   cannot access Internet URL
>   http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to handle this by editing your security sandbox.

But the easiest way to get this done would be to:

1. Install Apache on your windows machine (incase you want a faster way of managing a localhost server install WAMP/XAMPP, takes around 5 minutes to download and install)
2. Put the files under wamp/www/media

3.Instead of using

```
<mx:VideoDisplay id="vid" source="media/MyVideo.flv" height="250" width="250"/>
```

use

```
<mx:VideoDisplay id="vid" source="http://localhost/media/MyVideo.flv" height="250" width="250"/>
```

This should solve all the issues.

PS:It seems you want to create a web application and not a desktop application , because of which this issue is coming.Had you been using an AIR application , the local security sandbox exception would not have arose.

Comment: Yes, either u are allowed to use Local files or you are allowed to access network files, you can't access both at the same time. you can follow what @neeraj has opted or think about alternatively going for  a Desktop AIR version if you want to access both...